# Is React still part of the Truffle framework?

Tags: truffle, react

Is React still part of the Truffle framework? Need to set up a truffle project and would like to use React but not sure if it is still part of the truffle framework/family. Thanks, Manj

Answer (score 1):

Truffle has the react box you can use to get started on that framework.

https://github.com/truffle-box/react-box

```
truffle unbox react
```

Comment: I'll take that as a yes, then:) Many thanks, Shawn!